# Bitcoin Mixing? Is it even real?

Tags: security, privacy, mixing

I have been trying to find a "bitcoin mixing" service but it seems that ALL the "bitcoin mixing" sites I have looked at are scam. Does anybody know of any that are actually real and do what they say they do??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Wasabi Wallet https://www.wasabiwallet.io/ it is a privacy focused wallet and comes with a built-in coinjoin feature.